# Vertex color is not interpolated in the context of ID3DXLine

Tags: directx, hlsl

I've created a standard Win32 DirectX9 window and I'm rendering to it using a custom effect, however I have a problem where the colours of vertices are not interpolated in the result.

```
void CRender::Begin()
{
    perf.begin();

    // Capture device state so it can be restored later.
    // We use ID3DXLine::Begin() to fix some bugs that I don't know how to fix.
    mpLine->Begin();

    // Setup shader
    shader.Begin( static_cast<float>(FloatTime()) );
}
void CRender::End()
{
    // Reverse order of Begin()
    shader.End();
    mpLine->End();
}
```

The problem here lies with mpLine->Begin(), without calling this I get a perfectly nice interpolated triangle, with it the whole triangle has the same colour as the first vertex.
Image for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9SQn.png

I am using ID3DXLine::Begin() just to set up the device state for me. The reason I am using it is because I'm rendering in the context of another program (a game) by hooking its EndScene(). The game may leave the device in an unusable state causing rendering glitches in my overlay, all these problems go away when using ID3DXLine::Begin() except vertex colours aren't interpolated any more.

Vertex declaration:

```
// Create the vertex declaration for use with the shaders.
static const D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vformat[] =
{
    { 0, 0,  D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2,   D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0 },
    { 0, 8,  D3DDECLTYPE_D3DCOLOR, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR,    0 },
    { 0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2,   D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0 },
    D3DDECL_END()
};
HRESULT hr = dev->CreateVertexDeclaration( vformat, &decl );
```

Effect source:

```
// Vertex shader input
struct VSIN
{
    float2 coord  : POSITION;
    float4 color  : COLOR0;
    float2 tex    : TEXCOORD0;
};
// Vertex shader output / Pixel shader input
struct VSOUT
{
    float4 coord  : POSITION;
    float4 color  : COLOR0;
    float2 tex    : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 pos    : TEXCOORD1;
};

uniform float2 screen;
uniform float2x4 project;

float4 vstransform( float2 coord, const float2 shift )
{
    float2 final = ( mul( project, float4(coord.x,coord.y,1,1) ) + shift ) * 2 / screen;
    return float4( final.x-1, 1-final.y, 0, 1 );
}

VSOUT vsfix( VSIN data )
{
    VSOUT vert;
    const float2 shift = { -0.5f, -0.5f };
    vert.coord = vstransform( data.coord, shift );
    vert.color = data.color;
    vert.tex = data.tex;
    vert.pos = vert.coord.xy;
    return vert;
}

float4 diffuse( VSOUT vert ) : COLOR
{
    float4 px = vert.color;
    return px;
}

technique Diffuse
{
    pass p0
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 diffuse();
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 vsfix();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Ah, my bad. The question here is why the color isn't interpolated between the vertices when ID3DXLine::Begin() is called, as shown in the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/vKN4SnE.png). To me this means that ID3DXLine::Begin() adjusts the device state (as I am expecting it to do), however it is unexpected that color interpolation stops working.